# Having trouble passing a pointer to a function, again

Tags: c++, pointers, parameter-passing

Trying to pass the root of my Binary Search Tree **(BST)** to the **UI** function (I need to pass it as a modifiable variable or however it's called)

**main.cpp**

```
cmd = UI.uiCmd()

BST<Matrix> *data = new BST<Matrix>;
Matrix mat;

UI.handle (cmd, mat, data); // passing command, class object, root of BST
```

The UI class in the **header** has:

```
private:
void handle (int, Matrix, BST<Matrix *>);
```

and in the **.cpp** file:

```
void ui::handle(int cmd, Matrix matrix, BST<Matrix *> data)
```

I know I'm messing up somewhere but I can't say where, I have a very poor grasp of pointers

**The error I get:** it thinks `BST<Matrix>&*` while function asks `BST<Matrix> *`

I don't plan on using C++ much for now, so a detailed answer (while appreciated) is not necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function signature should look like

```
void handle (int, Matrix, BST<Matrix>*)
```

instead of

```
void handle (int, Matrix, BST<Matrix *>)
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly `BST<Matrix *>` is not the same as `BST<Matrix>*`. One is a container of pointers, the other is a pointer to a container.

Secondly, if you want to let the function modify an argument, you can pass it by reference:

```
void ui::handle(int cmd, sMat matrix, BST<sMat>& data)
```

and call it like

```
cmd = UI.uiCmd() 

BST<Matrix> data;
Matrix mat; 

UI.handle(cmd, mat, data);
```

Comment: if I have declaration `BST<sMat>* data` and then `void ui::handle(int cmd, sMat matrix, BST<sMat>* data)` would it still modify my data or do I have to use `&` also why ?

Comment: using `&` means you don't have to pass around pointers. `&` references can never be null. Because you can pass around normal stack-based instances of a class, you don't need to use `new` and you don't need to worry about using `delete` later or `std::shared_ptr<T>` or any other memory management technique. If you are definitely going to use pointers, then there's no need to worry about `&` references.

Answer (score 1):

You have created

```
    BST<Matrix> *data = new BST<Matrix>;
```

but the function asked for a `BST<Matrix*>` argument. Note the subtle difference

```
    BST<Matrix> * IS NOT same as  BST<Matrix*>
```

Comment: Ok, I understand the difference. I suppose I should have known that, but I find pointers utterly confusing. Thank you